# using only one button to play and pause a Mediaplayer in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android, my requirement is to use only one button for playing and pause using media player class?

Comment: any attempt? code? anything you did so far?

Comment: what stops you from achieving what you described?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your MediaPlayer set up, I would just set up in your onCreate() and onResume() methods, a check to see if the MediaPlayer is currently playing ([MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)'s `isPlaying()` method should work for you), and if it is playing, set the button's image and click handler to change it to a pause button. If the MediaPlayer isn't playing, then set it to be a play button.

You'll also need to handle listening for events such as when the MediaPlayer stops (finishes playing the audio file), as well as inverting the button state when you press it (i.e. pressing play changes button to pause, and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

I would use 2 buttons and hide one of them:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button playBtn;
    Button pauseBtn;

    public void onCreate() {
        playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        pauseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        pauseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.playButton:
            // play music here
            playBtn.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.pauseButton:
            // pause music here
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
            playBtn.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a single *Imagebutton* and change the drawable image , in conjuction with a toggling boolean variable to check the state of the button (play/pause).
This is how I implemented it

```
ImageButton playButton;
private boolean playOn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // some code here
    playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    //other specifications and your code
    }

public void play(View view){   
        myplayfunction();
}

public void myplayfunction(){
    if (playOn){
        playOn=false;
        playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icn_pause);
    //your mediaplayer functions
    }else{
        playOn=true;
        playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icn_play);
    //pause the mediaplayer
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to toggle your imagebutton at the end, *onCompletionListener()* method of the mediaplayer

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me. The value of the "playedLength" variable should also be initialize to zero, and set the "mediaPlaying" boolean value to false in the media player stop function to avoid errors.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button btnPlay;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private String mFileName = null;
private int playedLength; //variable for the CurrentPosition of audio when paused
private boolean mediaPlaying;  // boolean variable for toggling play, pause and resume actions

// some custom codes for my app...
```

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// some custom codes for my app.....

btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);

btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mediaPlaying){
            mediaPlaying = false;

            //pause the media player
            mPlayer.pause();
            playedLength = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_pause_focused_background);
        }else{
            mediaPlaying = true;
            if(mPlayer == null){
                // create the media player
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                    mPlayer.start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                }      
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_play_focused_background);
                } else
                    // resume playing
                    mPlayer.seekTo(playedLength);
                    mPlayer.start();
                  btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_play_focused_background);
            }
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button bPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
            MediaPlayer song1 = MediaPlayer.create(tutorialFour.this, R.raw.fluet);
        Button bStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bStop);
        bPlay.setWidth(10);
        song1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                bPlay.setText("Play");


            }
        });
        bPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                b=true;

                if(bPlay.getText().equals("Play") && b==true)
                {

                    song1.start();

                    bPlay.setText("Pause");
                    b=false;
                }

                else if(bPlay.getText().equals("Pause"))
                {
                    x=song1.getCurrentPosition();
                    song1.pause();
                    bPlay.setText("Resume");
                    Log.v("log",""+x);
                    b=false;
                }
                else if(bPlay.getText().equals("Resume") && b==true)
                {
                    song1.seekTo(x);
                    song1.start();
                    bPlay.setText("Pause");
                    b=false;
                }


            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:onClick="Play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="243dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="163dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:text="@string/play"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        boolean isPlaing = true;
        Button buttonPlay;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            buttonPlay = findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);

            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.stuff);


        }

        public void Play(View view) {
            if(isPlaing) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlay.setText("Pause");
                isPlaing = false;
            }else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlay.setText("Play");
                isPlaing = true;
            }
        }

    }
```