# Animated Image button that plays when clicked

Tags: android, android-animation, imagebutton

I am trying to create a media player and in that I want to make the <kbd>Play</kbd> button transform  to <kbd>Pause</kbd> button when clicked and again transform back to <kbd>Play</kbd> button when clicked again. It's a `.gif` image which I want to play forward upon first click and play backward upon second click. There are many tutorials about how to add an image as a button in android but none of them talks about button with animation that plays upon clicking. I am sure this is supported because I have seen similar applications. I want to know what is the correct way to do this? So it's not performance expensive and also works correctly regardless of the environment. Also I would appreciate a minimal example if possible.

**UPDATE:**

As a real close example to what I have in mind can be the Sony Xperia (Z1 or Z Ultra models to be specific) walkman app. This is a [sample](http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=17494) image to clarify things further.

Comment: The minimal code would be achieved by using **2** different images and assigning one or the other to the same ImageButton, depending on the button status. You can also use an ImageView or a TextView (they are clickable). Or a ToggleButton. Or...

Comment: could you please provide a more detailed answer in the answer section?

Comment: A quick search on Google led (lead? sorry, I'm not motherlanguage) me to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22933498/2649012

Comment: @DerGolem this is fine but i am looking for a way / trick to do it with an animation not just changing the text or an image to another image in a tick.

Comment: FYI: **A TextView can also hold drawables inside it**, not only text. An animation wold require MORE CODE, so it's **not an optimized way** to do the TRICK. I'm old, I have a certain experience, let me suggest you that **2 distinct** images (or drawables) will perform **better**, in terms of code - and speed.

Comment: @DerGolem are you talking about compound drawables? Why would you use a TextView for this, anyway? He already has the animated frames, so an ImageView or ImageButton seems like the right way to go.

Comment: @anakin78z: Because I would NOT use an animation. And a TextView is lightweight - you can use a compound drawable or a background.

Comment: Well, I guess Leonardo could have just written the words 'Mona Lisa' on a piece of parchment for efficiency, but I'm kind of glad he didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) (link contains example).

I don't see a way to play it in reverse, so you'd probably create 2 of them, one with the images playing forward, one with them playing backward. In your button OnClickListener, set the drawable to one animation or the other as needed, then start() the animation.

To use this technique you'll have to convert your gif into individual frames. There are a good number of free tools you can use to do this.

Example code:

```
public class AnimationDrawableButtonActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private AnimationDrawable[] mAnimations;
    private int mAnimationIndex = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation_drawable_button);
        new LoadAnimationTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    class LoadAnimationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AnimationDrawable[]>{


        @Override
        protected AnimationDrawable[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            AnimationDrawable[] animations = new AnimationDrawable[2];
            animations[0] = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_pause);
            animations[1] = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_pause_reverse);
            animations[0].setOneShot(true);
            animations[1].setOneShot(true);
            return animations;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AnimationDrawable[] animationDrawables) {
            super.onPostExecute(animationDrawables);

            mAnimations = animationDrawables;

            final ImageButton playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mAnimationIndex = (mAnimationIndex+ 1) %2;
                    playButton.setImageDrawable(mAnimations[mAnimationIndex]);
                    mAnimations[mAnimationIndex].start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

play_pause.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_022" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_023" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_024" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_025" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_026" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
</animation-list>
```

play_pause_reverse.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_026" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_025" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_024" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_023" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_022" android:duration="@integer/play_pause_duration" />
</animation-list>
```

ints.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="play_pause_duration">32</integer>
</resources>
```

activity_animation_drawable_button.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/play_pause_022"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: As suggested in the link you provided it looks like i have to break down my animation into many images and then add the frames one by one with a duration but animating this way will give me a performance expensive inflation because i want to have a smooth animation so i have to add many frames this way. Is there any better trick?

Comment: Is that assumption of bad performance based on anything? What makes you think you can't get smooth animation? Seems like it wouldn't take that long to try and find out.

Comment: well, actually learning about android I was told that since the GUI upon start or change must be inflated from an `.xml` file we should be really careful about how much we put in the file and not cause so much computing cycles as this is not a good practice in mobile app development. Please check the sample I have added to description and let me know if I'm worrying too much and that's not the case with what I want to do.

Comment: You can always load it in a separate thread using AsyncTask to make things easy, then assign it to the button once loaded. It's probably a good idea to do that, since you'll be loading two animation drawables (one to play forward, one to play backward). You can use one of the frames as a placeholder, or fade in the button once it's ready, but in reality it'll probably load so fast that it won't be an issue.

Comment: Just tried it using your example file. Works totally fine. Adding sample code above shortly.

Comment: Code posted. By the way, once I converted the gif file to individual images, I saw that I only needed 5 of them (the rest were just duplicates), but I have no reason to believe this won't work with more images.

Comment: thanks a lot. If possible please provide the `.xml` file for the UI as well, as it could be useful to newbies who might have the same interest. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, added code for all the resource files. Anything more and I'll  have to charge you ;)